# Finding all cases where a sub-condition is matched SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, conditional-statements, where-clause

I've got a dataset with lots of 'projects' from various suppliers, each one containing hundreds of different "objectives" from a masterlist with outcomes either "achieved" or "unrealised"

Some of these objectives are also listed in a second column "external_objectives" which are from a second source.

I want to create a list of unique 'projects' from a single supplier 'Walmart' where all "objectives" marked as "achieved" are present in both "objective" and "external_objective". The presence of "unrealised" objectives in the projects doesn't matter, but I want to exclude all projects where there are "achieved" that are not present in both "objectives" and "external_objectives".

| project | objective | external_objective | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b12345 | abcdef | abcdef | achieved |
| c23456 | abcdeg |  | achieved |
| d23456 | bbcdvg |  | unrealised |
| b12345 | ghfjds |  | achieved |
| d23456 | fghjka | fghjka | achieved |

So I would want to select project 'd23456' from this list, but not 'b12345' or 'c23456'

What I have so far is below and I'm pretty sure it's wrong.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Project 
FROM dataset
WHERE supplier="walmart" AND 
status = "achieved" AND objectives IS NOT NULL AND external_objectives IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY project
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition to be satisfied in order for the rows to be caught is that the amount of records for which "objective = external_objective" should be equal to the full amount of retrieved records, for the specific project.

You can use Google BigQuery [`COUNTIF`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators?hl=it#countif) to apply conditional aggregation within the `COUNT` aggregate function.

```
SELECT Project 
FROM dataset
WHERE supplier = "walmart" AND status = 'achieved'
GROUP BY Project
HAVING COUNTIF(objective = external_objective) = COUNT(project)
```

Comment: Hey, would this not only select projects without any "unrealised" at all?

Also, isn't COUNTIF not an SQL function? What would be the SQL equivalent?

Comment: You tagged Google BigQuery. `COUNTIF` is a Google BigQuery function. Additionally, note that "unrealised" status is not considered at all, as required in the problem statement, because the `WHERE` clause has priority on all other clauses.

Comment: (except the `FROM` clause, that defines the table(s) to use for the query)